# Server Error in '/' Application. <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">

Tags: c#, asp.net

I added this code to Web.config  then I uploaded my project or my website to Godaddy Server, and it shows me this error. 
Could anybody please help me out to solve to problem?
Thanks guys!

```
![Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information][1]
```

Server Error in '/' Application.

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.



Exception Details: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Source Error: 


Line 74:                         </td>
Line 75:                         <td style="text-align: right">
Line 76:                             **<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">**
Line 77:                             </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
Line 78:                             <asp:Label ID="Label25" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="X-Small" Text=" DD/MM/YYYY"></asp:Label>

Source File: d:\hosting\11645199\html\newstudents.aspx    Line: 76 

Stack Trace:
```

Comment: Im having the same problem with my GoDaddy server. Runs fine when using regular ScriptManager. But then my CalendarExtenders fail to work. Will try and find some info via GoDaddy.

Comment: I change the trust level in the web.config.  `<system.web>
    <trust level="Full"/></system.web>`. Now it works for me on the GoDaddy server also!

Answer (score 1):

Try by changing Ajax toolkit version. Please make sure that it is latest one.

Comment: This should've been a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added this code??

```
  <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```